# how to fetch string separated by special character caret '^' using grep

Tags: grep, special-characters, caret

I have following string in text file:

```
^25555555~BIG^20200629^20022222^20200629^55555555^^^DI^00~CUR^ZZ^USD
```

and want to fetch string between `BIG^` and `^00` i.e.
`20200629^20022222^20200629^25523652^^^DI`. I tried to use following command but it is not working, may be because of special character caret `^`.

```bash
echo "^25555555~BIG^20200629^20022222^20200629^25523652^^^DI^00~CUR^ZZ^USD" | grep -o -P '(?<=BIG^).*(?=^00)'
```

I tried removing caret from search and it is working but need to include caret in my search:

```bash
echo "^25555555~BIG^20200629^20022222^20200629^55555555^^^DI^00~CUR^ZZ^USD" | grep -o -P '(?<=BIG).*(?=00)'
```

above command returns: `^20200629^20022222^20200629^55555555^^^DI^`

How to fetch part of string from string containing special character caret ^ using grep?

Comment: Use `grep -oP '(?<=BIG\^).*(?=\^00)'`

Comment: I am able get su-string using following command: echo 'BIG^20210303^2222222^2222222^1520612887^^^DI^00~CUR^ZZ^USD' | cut -d'^' -f 3

Comment: Your comment is not clear. What is not working with my suggested grep command?

Answer (score 2):

The regex pattern should be `BIG\^(.*)\^00`
will grab this:

```
BIG^20200629^20022222^20200629^55555555^^^DI^00
```

and the item in group `(1)` is your value `20200629^20022222^20200629^55555555^^^`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```bash
grep -oP 'BIG\^\K.*?(?=\^00)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z7hpu7/1).

*Details*:

- `BIG\^` - a `BIG^` string
- `\K` - a match reset operator that omits the text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\^00)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `^00` string immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Your solution has worked to get required sub string. Do you know how to split string by caret separator.

Comment: @PravinB Yes, see [this Bash demo](https://ideone.com/VfrrIY).